# How to union mutliple databases with join clause

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 databases with the same tables. Now I would like to union the 3 tables from different databases and on each table make a join to pull additional information. Unfortunately this is not working because the syntax is incorrect. Is this possible to do ?

like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (

    SELECT ID, [Address], Matchcode, [Name], Country, Place, ZIP, Street FROM [Czech].[dbo].[Addresses] a
        LEFT JOIN [Czech].[dbo].[Account] k ON (a.ID = k.ID AND a.Address = k.Address)
        UNION
    SELECT ID, [Address], Matchcode, [Name], Country, Place, ZIP, Street FROM [Germany].[dbo].[Addresses] a
        LEFT JOIN [Germany].[dbo].[Account] k ON (a.ID = k.ID AND a.Address = k.Address)
        UNION
    SELECT ID, [Address], Matchcode, [Name], Country, Place, ZIP, Street FROM [Austria].[dbo].[Addresses] a
        LEFT JOIN [Austria].[dbo].[Account] k ON (a.ID = k.ID AND a.Address = k.Address)

) AS AddressAll WHERE [Address] = '1010'
```

In my account tables I have some specfific columns for each address like sales, amount, taxID, lastSale,....
Unfortunately we have 3 comapnies that are in different countries thats why there are 3 tables.

The goal is to use the WHERE clause on this multiple tables.

Comment: your syntax looks correct to me, are your databases hosted in the same instance?

Comment: yes. Im getting an error : `ID, Address, Matchcode. sql ambiguous column name` translated from german

Comment: it means in `[Czech].[dbo].[Addresses]` and `[Czech].[dbo].[Account]` (and so for other databases/countries) you may have columns with same name. Specify the table alias and then it would work. Like:  `SELECT a.ID, a.[Address], k.Matchcode, k.[Name] ...`

Comment: Incorrect does not give us much to go on.